# In need of help to create a while loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop

This is my code for printing out the list:

```
my_shopping_list = ["Bread", "Milk" , "Coke" , "Eggs" , "Cheese"]
for item in my_shopping_list:
    print(item)
```

But I need to print out the first 3 items of the list **I have and have to use a `while` loop** for it.

So the items I need printed out are `Bread`, `Milk` and `Coke`.

Comment: Why do you want to use a while loop for this? This would idiomatically be solve by slicing or ``enumerate``ing the items. What other restrictions do you have?

Comment: You can slice my_shopping_list for only 3 first items by my_shopping_list[0:3] and thus print only 3 first items

Comment: @AnnZen I would prefer not to guess. If it is an exercise, [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) applies, and it would be helpful to know what the asker is struggling with when applying a ``while`` loop.

Comment: @AnnZen Well then it would be good not having to guess whether it is *homework* exercise, *some* exercise or no exercise.

Comment: @AnnZen Pardon? I do not follow what are you are meaning to say. I know neither which millions of questions you mean, nor how they relate to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
my_shopping_list = ["Bread", "Milk" , "Coke" , "Eggs" , "Cheese"]

n=0 

while n<3:
    print(my_shopping_list[n])
    n+=1
```

Output:

```
Bread
Milk
Coke
```

Answer (score 0):

just by a slight change

```
for item in my_shopping_list[:3]:
    print(item)
```

you can get the first three elements of the list with for-loop indeed.

If you want to use while-loop, then consider writing the code as

```
i=0
while i<3:
    print(my_shopping_list[i])
    i+=1
```

Comment: It must be a while loop

Comment: Why @IoaTzimas ?

Comment: This is what he is asking for. See the title too